# VS Code Extension: get the Quick Fixes and apply them

Tags: javascript, vscode-extensions, quickfix

I am trying to build a vs code extension where I pull the diagnostics for a document using following code

```
const diagnostics = vscode.languages.getDiagnostics(document.uri);
```

I am able to get the diagnostics properly (as per the Problems view), but I am not able figure out how to get the QuickFixes for each diagnotics (Show Fixes lightbulb in Problems view).

I tried following approaches:

1. getting the codeActions using

```
const codeActions = await vscode.commands.executeCommand("vscode.executeCodeActionProvider", document.uri,element.range);
```

and filtered on `vscode.CodeActionKind.QuickFix` actions. But, I am not getting any codeactions of this kind. I tried checking `codeAction.edit` as well and it is empty.

2. tried checking the diagnostics array, but nothing related to fixes. For example. there is a diagnostic for a module not defined and `code` has the value as `reportUndefinedVariable`, but no more info

Following is the dignostics array:

```
[
  {
    "severity": "Warning",
    "message": "\"date_converter\" is not defined",
    "range": [
      {
        "line": 14,
        "character": 41
      },
      {
        "line": 14,
        "character": 55
      }
    ],
    "source": "Pylance",
    "code": {
      "value": "reportUndefinedVariable",
      "target": {
        "$mid": 1,
        "path": "/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/configuration.md",
        "scheme": "https",
        "authority": "github.com",
        "fragment": "reportUndefinedVariable"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "severity": "Warning",
    "message": "\"date_converter\" is not defined",
    "range": [
      {
        "line": 19,
        "character": 41
      },
      {
        "line": 19,
        "character": 55
      }
    ],
    "source": "Pylance",
    "code": {
      "value": "reportUndefinedVariable",
      "target": {
        "$mid": 1,
        "path": "/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/configuration.md",
        "scheme": "https",
        "authority": "github.com",
        "fragment": "reportUndefinedVariable"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "severity": "Warning",
    "message": "\"date_converter\" is not defined",
    "range": [
      {
        "line": 35,
        "character": 25
      },
      {
        "line": 35,
        "character": 39
      }
    ],
    "source": "Pylance",
    "code": {
      "value": "reportUndefinedVariable",
      "target": {
        "$mid": 1,
        "path": "/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/configuration.md",
        "scheme": "https",
        "authority": "github.com",
        "fragment": "reportUndefinedVariable"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "severity": "Warning",
    "message": "\"date_converter\" is not defined",
    "range": [
      {
        "line": 40,
        "character": 25
      },
      {
        "line": 40,
        "character": 39
      }
    ],
    "source": "Pylance",
    "code": {
      "value": "reportUndefinedVariable",
      "target": {
        "$mid": 1,
        "path": "/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/configuration.md",
        "scheme": "https",
        "authority": "github.com",
        "fragment": "reportUndefinedVariable"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "severity": "Hint",
    "message": "\"datetime\" is not accessed",
    "range": [
      {
        "line": 3,
        "character": 7
      },
      {
        "line": 3,
        "character": 15
      }
    ],
    "source": "Pylance"
  },
  {
    "severity": "Hint",
    "message": "\"pytz\" is not accessed",
    "range": [
      {
        "line": 4,
        "character": 7
      },
      {
        "line": 4,
        "character": 11
      }
    ],
    "source": "Pylance"
  },
  {
    "severity": "Error",
    "message": "Failure",
    "range": [
      {
        "line": 0,
        "character": 0
      },
      {
        "line": 0,
        "character": 0
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am new to VS code extension development. Can you please help me with an approach to resolve this?